# Using drop down widget from ipywidgets

Tags: python, data-science, ipywidgets

I am trying to use a drop down and store the selected value to a local variable. Although the print statement works, it's not storing the value to a variable. Any and all help will be highly appreciated.

```
import ipywidgets as widgets

bor = 'A'
drop_down = widgets.Dropdown(options=['A','B','C','D'],
                                description='Choose',
                                disabled=False)

def dropdown_handler(change):
        print(change.new)
        bor = change.new  # This line isn't working
drop_down.observe(dropdown_handler, names='value')
display(drop_down)
```

[Relevant photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmPRx.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! I would try first writing `bor = change.new` and then writing `print(bor)`. Not sure if it will help, but it is possible that `change.new` works like a generator and can only be called once.

Comment: @Mathchiller thank you for answering , but I did try that too. Didn;t work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function *is* working, but it assigns `bor` in the local namespace of the function, which is then lost when the function completes.

You will need to declare `global bor` in your `dropdown_handler` function. Then you should be able to call `bor` in the global namespace and get the result set by the dropdown.

```
import ipywidgets as widgets

bor = 'A'
drop_down = widgets.Dropdown(options=['A','B','C','D'],
                                description='Choose',
                                disabled=False)

def dropdown_handler(change):
    global bor
    print(change.new)
    bor = change.new  # This line isn't working
drop_down.observe(dropdown_handler, names='value')
display(drop_down)
```