# Is there a way to use this dropdown menu to assign a variable value - Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, drop-down-menu, python-3.10

```py
from ipywidgets import widgets

options = ["1", "2","3"]
dropdown= widgets.Dropdown(options=options)
display(dropdown)

x = dropdown.value
```

Every time I run this the x variable is read at 1, even when I change the drop down in the notebook.

Just need the x variable to be the option that was selected in the drop down menu.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The value of x must be updated when the dropdown value is changed. Perhaps in your code, rather than using the variable x, simply use 'dropdown.value'.
Otherwise, if storing in a variable is essential, an on_change function can be used.

```
from ipywidgets import widgets
options = ["1", "2","3"]
dropdown = widgets.Dropdown(options=options) 
x=dropdown.value
def on_change(change):
    if change['type'] == 'change' and change['name'] == 'value':
        x = change['new']
    
dropdown.observe(on_change)
display(dropdown)
```

This code causes the on_change function to be called each time the dropdown item is changed, causing the x variable to be updated.

Comment: This does not change the value of `x`, since it is assigned in the local namespace of the function `on_change`. You have to declare `x` to be global (`global x`) before you change the value.
The answer to this question shows how this works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61821652/using-drop-down-widget-from-ipywidgets